# Oracle Select Query based on a column value

Tags: oracle, query-performance, query

I have two tables and wanted to conditionally query one of the tables.
For example below are the two tables with few matching columns in two tables
Table A(SNO, Number,Name...)
Table B ( SNO, Number,FullName..)
Number column value is passed to the query dynamically.
Table A and B have matching Columns(SNO,Number)
I would like to run a query on table based on the value of Number column which is common in both tables.

Something like this
if number =12
Select Query on Table A
else
select Query on Table B

Comment: So, can you [edit] your question to provide a more detailed example of your `if Number = 12`:  IE: what table are you looking at when checking `Number = 12`, Table A?  Table B?  A different table?  Since you tagged this with pl/sql, are you implying you want to do dynamic SQL and `execute immediate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union to select from two tables like follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE number = 12
AND  {other conditions}
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE number != 12
AND  {other conditions}
```